# Merging columns with a key that tells which column should be prioritized based on suffix R

Tags: r, database, dplyr, data.table

I have the following dataframe:

```
set.seed(123)
    df <- data.frame(col.dfA=rnorm(8,40,2),
                     col.dfB=rnorm(8,20,2),
                     colt=rnorm(8,100,20),
                     pr.dfA=rnorm(8,20,2),
                     pr.dfB=rnorm(8,30,2),
                     priority=c("dfA","dfB","dfA","dfA","dfB","dfA","dfB","dfB"))
```

Now I would like to merge `col.dfA`&`col.dfB` and `pr.dfA`&`pr.dfB`into `df$col` and `df$pr` respectively.
The `df$priority` column gives indication which column values should be used in each row. Ie. in the 1st, 3rd, 4th and 6th rows, columns with suffix `dfA` should be prioritised. In remaining rows columns with suffix `dfB` should be prioritised. The solution needs to be applicable for larger scenarios with dozens of columns and hundreds of rows.

Initial dataframe:

```
   col.dfA  col.dfB      colt   pr.dfA   pr.dfB priority
1 38.87905 18.62629 109.95701 18.74992 31.79025      dfA
2 39.53965 19.10868  60.66766 16.62661 31.75627      dfB
3 43.11742 22.44816 114.02712 21.67557 31.64316      dfA
4 40.14102 20.71963  90.54417 20.30675 31.37728      dfA
5 40.25858 20.80154  78.64353 17.72373 31.10784      dfB
6 43.43013 20.22137  95.64050 22.50763 29.87618      dfA
7 40.92183 18.88832  79.47991 20.85293 29.38807      dfB
8 37.46988 23.57383  85.42218 19.40986 29.23906      dfB
```

Expected result:

```
  col      colt      pr            priority
1 38.87905 109.95701 18.74992      dfA
2 19.10868  60.66766 31.75627      dfB
3 43.11742 114.02712 21.67557      dfA
4 40.14102  90.54417 20.30675      dfA
5 20.80154  78.64353 31.10784      dfB
6 43.43013  95.64050 22.50763      dfA
7 18.88832  79.47991 29.38807      dfB
8 23.57383  85.42218 29.23906      dfB
```

Comment: Please show the expected output

Comment: @akrun I added expected output. thank you

Comment: Are you sure you ran this output with the correct seed?

Comment: @MichaelChirico I am sure I did, maybe I wasn't clear that I showed the expected result. Now both df and the expected result can be seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you try it this way:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  gather(key = 'varname', value = 'varvalue', 
         matches(paste(.$priority, collapse = '|'))) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  filter(grepl(priority, varname)) %>%
  mutate(varname = gsub('\\.[[:alpha:]]+$', '', varname)) %>%
  spread(key = varname, value = varvalue)
```

Comment: Add `%>% 
  arrange(rn) %>% 
  select(-(rn))` at the end I get exactly what I need!

Comment: I like the simplicity of this, it feels like you only toss the data, but finally it gives you what you need.

Comment: sadly when i execute it with my large database, i get an error: `Error in grep(needle, haystack, ...) : 
  invalid regular expression 'dfA|dfA|dfA....` it happens already at the `gather` execution

Comment: How about if we assume we have dfA and dfB and we need to look for columns with those suffixes only?

Comment: yes, that was overkill, just realized that. Does `matches('dfA|dfB$')` instead of `matches(paste(.$priority, collapse = '|'))` works? Without `dfA|dfB' asumption it might be ``matches(paste(unique(.$priority), collapse = '|'))`...

Comment: yippie it did!! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative approach which uses the ability of [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table)'s incarnation of `melt()` to reshape multiple value columns simultaneously:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)  # used to improve readability
# pick column names ending in .dfA or .dfB
pat <- names(df) %>% stringr::str_extract(".+\\.df(?=[AB]$)") %>% unique() %>% na.omit()
# new column names without trailing .df
col <- pat %>% stringr::str_replace("\\.df$", "")
# reshape from wide to  long format
melt(setDT(df)[, rn := .I], measure.vars = patterns(pat), value.name = col)[
  # subset rows where priority equals variable (as factor levels)
  as.integer(priority) == as.integer(variable)][
    # re-order and clean up
    order(rn)][, variable := NULL][]
```

> ```
>         colt priority rn      col       pr
> 1: 109.95701      dfA  1 38.87905 18.74992
> 2:  60.66766      dfB  2 19.10868 31.75627
> 3: 114.02712      dfA  3 43.11742 21.67557
> 4:  90.54417      dfA  4 40.14102 20.30675
> 5:  78.64353      dfB  5 20.80154 31.10784
> 6:  95.64050      dfA  6 43.43013 22.50763
> 7:  79.47991      dfB  7 18.88832 29.38807
> 8:  85.42218      dfB  8 23.57383 29.23906
> ```

Comment: This is great, thank you @Uwe . Chose other answer only because it was slightly more compact.

Comment: It actually gets messy if it looks for more suffixes. How about if we assume we have dfA and dfB and we need to look for columns with those suffixes only?

Comment: Well, actually this is what the code does. It looks for columns whose names end on `".dfA"`or `".dfB"`, resp., and creates a pattern from it which is used in the call to `melt()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you're after... but I think it's this:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df, key = 'priority')
df[.('dfA'), c('col', 'pr') := .(col.dfA, pr.dfA)]
df[.('dfB'), c('col', 'pr') := .(col.dfB, pr.dfB)]
```

Drop source columns if so desired:

```
df[ , grep('\\.df[AB]$', names(df)) := NULL][]
#         colt priority      col       pr
# 1:  66.99376      dfA 40.81422 22.05758
# 2: 104.97938      dfA 41.09455 19.78682
# 3:  66.33725      dfA 40.08257 21.65990
# 4: 112.25391      dfA 42.89993 19.72432
# 5:  72.14824      dfB 23.47501 30.76038
# 6: 103.57393      dfB 19.43745 26.52382
# 7:  93.28548      dfB 20.46695 29.38035
# 8:  89.28845      dfB 19.21581 28.66537
```

Use `setcolorder` if that matters to you to re-order columns.

A more programmatic generalization could use `mget`:

```
priorities = unique(df$priority)
nm = names(df)
merge_col = unique(c(sapply(priorities, function(suff) {
  has_suff = grepl(sprintf('%s$', suff), nm)
  gsub(sprintf('\\.%s$', suff), '', nm[has_suff])
})))

for (PRIORITY in priorities) {
  source_cols = sprintf('%s.%s', merge_cols, PRIORITY)
  df[.(PRIORITY), (merge_cols) := mget(source_cols)]
  df[ , (source_cols) := NULL]
}
```

`mget` has been known to be slow. It may be more efficient to use `eval`:

```
df[.(PRIORITY), (merge_cols) := lapply(source_cols, function(x) eval(as.name(x)))]
```

Comment: thanks that works! butthe problem is that i have dozens of columns like that so need to streamline it without outlining the prefixes of the columns: c('col', 'pr'). Any advice on how to do it?

Comment: actually, I have dozens of prefixes and only two suffixes. So, the following line: merge_cols = c('col', 'pr') needs to be replaced with something more generic.

Comment: I replaced `merge_cols` with `merge_col` but still get the following error:
`Error in `:=`((merge_col), mget(source_cols)) : 
  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").`

Comment: @MIH Read the error message carefully; the two most common sources of this error are (1) `df` is not a `data.table` (run `setDT(df)`); (2) you've not put the `:=` part into the `j` argument (e.g. you're missing `i`); try explicitly writing `j = (merge_col) :=...`